# What’s this Spider-Man comic, and did it inspire a scene in Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man, avengers-infinity-war

I recently came across this image of Spider-Man which is very similar

> to his fate in ***Avengers: Infinity War*** (image below).

[image]

I'm looking for the exact source of this ***snap***-shot (*intended pun here*); the **comic-book issue** *etc*.

Also, is this the original source on which:

> Spider-Man's final words in ***Avengers: Infinity War*** before disintegrating

were based on?

Answer (score 11):

This is [Web of Spider-Man #45 (1985)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Vol_1_45). He's actually just knocked out from something the Vulture injected him with:

[image]

As for the scene in Infinity War:

> According to Reddit user Anewthrowaway_quest, [in a Q&A at their high school](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/8g10pg/joe_russo_came_and_had_a_qa_at_our_high_school/) Joe Russo said that Holland improvised the death scene in Infinity War.